# Querying month column of string datatype

Tags: soql, query, sql

I have a month column which has values like shown below

month
01
1
02
2
03
3
04
4
4
09
10
12

So, some of the values have leading zeros and some don't.
Now in SOQL query, I am using

SELECT xxxx
WHERE month >= '03'

Expected result should be
03
3
04
4
4
09
10
12

But I'm getting result as
1
2
03
3
04
4
4
09
10
12

So, it is not taking the values(without leading O's) into account. Is there anyway to cast the values to integer and compare

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is due to the way that the greater than operator works when comparing String values in Salesforce. The easiest way would be to create a formula field on your object that returns a number using the Value function and use this in your query. The documentation for that can be found here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_value.htm&type=5

Given the contents of the month field in your question however, I'd actually recommend looking at whether it is possible to look at converting this to a Number field. Depending on the length of this field or the method in which it is populated it may be a data quality issue currently.

Comment: Thanks @Callum MacErlich,
I'm actually constructing the query and making a rest request passing this query to salesforce to fetch the data. Yeah, not much can be done from the java service as I can only construct the query and pass it. The functionality of comparative operators is little different for strings, I understand that now, Thank you. Actually, I have raised a ticket for salesforce team to update the values and maintain consistency. I hope they resolve this soon.